# NodeJS. TypeError: https.request is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm programming a web application with AngularJS and I use NodeJS because of CORS problems. Well, when I'm trying to make the request in my node I get this error:

```
TypeError: https.request is not a function
at C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\index.js:56:22
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at cors (C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:188:7)
at C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:224:17
at originCallback (C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:214:15)
at C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:219:13
at optionsCallback (C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:199:9)
at corsMiddleware (C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:204:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\AgriWea\WebContent\js\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

My NodeJS file (index.js):

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var rootCas = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();
rootCas.addFile(__dirname + '/ssl/ovccatastromehes.crt');
const https = require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;
var request = require('request');

var app = express()

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extened:false}));
app.use(bodyparser.json()); 
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});


app.get('/space/:id', cors(), function (req, res) {
    var soapRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
            +'<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
            +'<soap:Body>'
                +'<Provincia xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"></Provincia>'
                +'<Municipio xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"></Municipio>'
                +'<SRS xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/">EPSG:4326</SRS>'
                +'<RefCat xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/">'+req.params.id+'</RefCat>'
            +'</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

    var options = {
        host: 'ovc.catastro.meh.es',
        path: '/ovcservweb/ovcswlocalizacionrc/ovccoordenadas.asmx',
        method: 'POST',
        headers : {
            "SOAPAction" : "http://tempuri.org/OVCServWeb/OVCCoordenadas/Consulta_CPMRC",
            "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
            "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(soapRequest)}
    };

    var httpreq = https.request(options, function (response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("body: " + chunk);
            res.send(chunk);
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            //res.send('ok');
        });
    });

    httpreq.write(soapRequest);
    httpreq.end();
});

app.listen(8100, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 8100')
});
```

The service where I call the node:

```
.factory("catastro", function($http, $sce) {
    /*
     *  INICIALIZACIÓN DE VARIABLES
    */
    var url = 'http://localhost:8100/space/';
    var cat = {};

    /*
     *  FUNCIONES
    */
    // Obtener XML por referencia catastral
    cat.leerReferenciaCatastral = function(rc) {
        var urladd = url + rc;
        return $http.get(urladd)
        .then(function(respuesta) {
            return respuesta.data;
        });
    };

    return cat;
})
```

It's my first time with NodeJS and I'm a bit lost. I've searched about 'https' and request IS a function... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

That's because you're trying to call the function `request` on the `rootCas` object:

```
const https = require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;
```

In other words, here you assign `rootCas` to both `require('https').globalAgent.options.ca` and `https`.

---

Instead, try this:

```
const https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;
```